# Get last day of the next three months with Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am heading to find out a formula for a date that is the last day of the next 3 months with Crystal Report. I've tried with the code as below but it shows a message when it is out of an array of month (1-12). Please give me any advice to address this problem.

```
ToText(date(year({rptIEXSaleInvoiceSummary.ETD}),month({rptIEXSaleInvoiceSummary.ETD})+4,1)-1, "dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

It works fine if the `ETD's month` is less than 8. However, it might cause problem when it is more than 9, 10 as an image below.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. Please let me know if you have any idea to solve the problem.

```
IF (month({rptIEXSaleInvoiceSummary.ETD})+4) > 12 THEN 
ToText(date(year({rptIEXSaleInvoiceSummary.ETD})+1,month({rptIEXSaleInvoiceSummary.ETD})-8,1)-1, "dd-MMM-yyyy")
ELSE
ToText(date(year({rptIEXSaleInvoiceSummary.ETD}),month({rptIEXSaleInvoiceSummary.ETD})+4,1)-1, "dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the 4th month use DateAdd

```
DateAdd(“m”,4,{rptIEXSaleInvoiceSummary.ETD})
```

Then you can compose the date

```
ToText(date(year(DateAdd(“m”,4,{rptIEXSaleInvoiceSummary.ETD})),month({rptIEXSaleInvoiceSummary.ETD}),1), "dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

or subtract days

DateAdd(“d”,day({rptIEXSaleInvoiceSummary.ETD}), DateAdd(“m”,4,{rptIEXSaleInvoiceSummary.ETD}))